# Why is a proper morphism between schemes an analog of a proper map between complex analytic spaces?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

As mentioned in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_morphism), a proper morphism between schemes is an analog of a proper map between complex analytic spaces.

Why is it so?

A proper morphism $f:X \to Y$ of schemes is by definition separated, of finite type and universally closed. If we view this morphism as a holomorphic map $f:X(\mathbb{C}) \to Y(\mathbb{C})$, then (I guess) separatedness and being of finite type should imply that each fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ is Hausdorff and finite dimensional, respectively. The "key" feature of a proper morphism is being universally closed, which (I guess) should imply that the pre-image $f^{-1}(A) \subset X(\mathbb{C})$ is compact for any compact subset $A \subset Y(\mathbb{C})$.

If my guesses are correct, then the question  becomes: why does universally closedness of the morphism $f:X \to Y$ imply that $f^{-1}(A) \subset X(\mathbb{C})$ is compact for any compact subset $A \subset Y(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Do you not see an analogy between proper as "universally closed map from Hausdorff to locally compact Hausdorff" and proper as "universally closed map of finite type and separated"? Both definitions are universally closed + finiteness assumption + separation assumption.

Comment: @KReiser I don't follow what you said. Are you trying to say a proper map between complex analytic spaces can be defined as a "universally closed map" from Hausdorff to locally compact Hausdorff?

Comment: Yes. For instance, this is in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map) for a proper map.

Comment: There is also the fact that if $f:X\to Y$ is a map of $\mathbb{C}$-varieties that it's proper if and only if its analytification is proper.

Comment: @AlexYoucis By analytification of $X$, you mean the analytic space $X(\mathbb{C})$ of complex points of $X$?

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for the wiki-link. I didn't know there is an analog of universally closed map in the category of topological spaces. I guess I still lack some intuition behind the notion of universally closed map. Apparently, it's same as closed with compact fibers when the source and target are "nice".

Comment: @YuhangChen Yes.